# Working with reledmac and manuscripts that contain footnotes

Tags: footnotes, reledmac

I am working on a critical edition of a French text. The original manuscript itself has footnotes, and I'm not sure how to handle this situation with reledmac.

I could just include the footnoted text as a familiar footnote in the document, but the trouble is that I need to be able to add annotations and textual variants for the footnoted text. For example, the following produces an error:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage[series={A,B},draft]{reledmac}
\newcommand{\annotation}[1]{\footnoteA{#1}}
\newcommand{\variant}[2]{\Afootnote{#1 \ #2}}

\begin{document}

\beginnumbering

\pstart
Je tâcherai de
\edtext{développer}{\annotation{FOOTNOTED TEXT ORIGINALLY IN MANUSCRIPT BLAH BLAH \edtext{BLAH}{\variant{BLAHH}{ms. 4}} END OF FOOTNOTED TEXT.}}
dans le troisième, pourquoy les corps opaques l'interrompent et la réfléchissent.
\pend

\end{document}
```

Is there a standard way of approaching this problem? I'm sure there are other hacky solutions to getting around it but I'm wondering if these is some native ability in `reledmac` for doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need footnote to comment footnote. Actually, there is no way to obtain it directly in reledmac. You could open an issue, but honestly I won't have time to look for it.

However, what you could do is using the `\lemma` command inside an \edtext{}, which will allow you to insert critical footnote with some content without typesetting this content in your text.

Combined  `\Xinplaceofnumber` and setting, you could get something as you expect.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage[series={A,B},draft]{reledmac}
\newcommand{\annotation}[1]{\footnoteA{#1}}
\Xnonumber[A]
\Xinplaceofnumber[A]{0pt}

\newcommand{\variantoffootnote}[2]{\edtext{}{\lemma{(\thefootnoteA) #1}\Afootnote[nonum]{#2}}}

\begin{document}

\beginnumbering

\pstart
Je tâcherai de
développer\annotation{FOOTNOTED TEXT ORIGINALLY IN MANUSCRIPT BLAH BLAH  END OF FOOTNOTED TEXT.}\variantoffootnote{BLAH BLAH}{BLAHBLAH en un seul mot}
dans le troisième, pourquoy les corps opaques l'interrompent et la réfléchissent\annotation{FOOTNOTED TEXT ORIGINALLY IN MANUSCRIPT BLAH BLAH  END OF FOOTNOTED TEXT.}\variantoffootnote{BLAH BLAH}{BLAHBLAH en un seul mot}.
\pend

\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks like something that will work. Very grateful.